# No such table exist in external sqlite database in android studio

Tags: java, android, database, android-sqlite, android-external-storage

**strong text**Hello Everyone in android Studio when i paste external sqlite database in Assets folder.it shows "such table not exist" in logcat android Studio. when I export same sqlite database.then there is no table no data.
Why it is happening.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> Why it is happening.

This will happen if the copy of the asset file fails BUT leaves a file (invalid such as empty) and the SQLiteDatabase openOrCreate() runs *(`openOrCreate` can be used on it's or as is typical it is called by `SQLiteOpenHelper` and therefore classes that extend it)*.

The `openOrCreate` will in the event of an invalid file, overwrite it with a valid **EMPTY** database.

There can be various reasons why the copy fails, common reasons are

- that the databases directory doesn't exist (`data/data/the_package_name/**databases**`), as it doesn't by default (until more recently where I think that it is now created),
- that a protected path has been specified (e.g. the package_name has been omitted or is wrong).
- that inconsistent paths have been used e.g. the file copy/check path is different to the path used to open the Database.

A very common cause is hard coding locations/paths instead of using the Context's `getDatabasePath` method.

**Exactly why would be dependant upon the code being used and the actual failure/exception recorded in the log.**

Comment: Hello MikeT i tried almost all different available solution but didn't solve my problem.                     my question is why table and data disappears from sqlite database in Android studio.Before  pasting it has table and data and after exporting it doesn't have any table and data.                           https://stackoverflow.com/a/69083135/9927024